# What would you call a group of people who don't mind their own business?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Scenario: You're building a model in your room. You've been building something incredibly intrinsic and you don't want to stop until it's finished. Your father comes in and begins to scold you for spending so much time on what he believes to be a "waste of time". Your sister overhears the argument and comes in to take your fathers' side, citing hazards from working with fumes. Your brother hears the commotion, comes in to check out the problem and compliments you on what you've built so far. Your siblings begin to argue between each other on their opposing opinions. Your mother hears the squabbling and defends you from your father. Both arguments veer away onto extraneous topics. You lose your concentration and break something crucial on your model. You turn to your family and blame them for distracting you. Probably saying something along the lines of, "This is your fault. You couldn't leave well enough alone. You all had to be a bunch of *_*_"?

Comment: 'busy-body' is the first that comes to mind, but sounds old-fashioned to me now. 'buttinsky' is what I would use for not minding their own business, but is too slangy...Wait, your title says 'mind your own business', but the content says 'discussing their own issues'. These are two different things.

Comment: Sounds to me like they're "uninvited/unwelcome guests". Why wouldn't the "owner" of the room just shut the door and not answer if he doesn't want company?

Comment: This is pretty much the definition of a busybody. BTW, I think you mean intricate, not intrinsic when discussing your model. Intricate    means complicated, intrinsic means belonging to, or essentially. You might say your model is intrinsically intricate!

Comment: You really should open a window for the fumes. Also, the lighting is probably not good for your eyes.

Comment: A good British phrase is 'nosey parkers'  http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/nosy-parker.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

People who **intrude** without due cause or permission are **interlopers**.  If the purpose of the intrusion was to deliberately interfere, then they could also be called **kibitzers**.

Comment: "Kibitzer" is usually applied to a person who watches other people playing a game (usually cards, but could be chess, etc.) and offers unwanted advice.  It's distracting and annoying, but a kibitzer would generally not interrupt the actual game.

Comment: @MT_Head Wow, learned a new one today. As a former chess player and now e-Sport fanatic, I've encountered more than my share of kibitzers - love it!

Comment: Interesting!  Everywhere that I looked agreed with that definition, but I played contract bridge for many years and kibitzers were common and sanctioned, but they never interrupted the game and offering of advice was very uncommon and certainly not essential to the activity.  I'd say that in that subculture it at least dropped and perhaps reversed that connotation.

Answer (score 15):

**Busybodies** is a group of meddlesome, prying, *officious*  people.

*Officious*: Marked by excessive eagerness in offering unwanted services or advice to others.

This seems to describe your situation to a tee (exactly).

Answer (score 4):

I can't add comments so I am using this section to tell you that you accepted the wrong answer.

As others have told you already, the best word to describe such behavior is *busybody*. If you don't want to use it, then *meddler* would be the best-fit.

But *interloper* or *kibitzer* aren't words that define what you are describing.

Comment: Meddler Is the best one here.

Answer (score 3):

***"party crashers", "hangers on" or "buttinskis"*** are all somewhat slangy but servicable words for that situation

Answer (score 1):

Technically they are minding their own business, they are just minding it on your patch. If they were poking their noses into your affairs, I would call them **nosey parkers**. However, in your example they don't appear to be being nosey. So I would be more likely to say:

"This is your fault. You couldn't leave well enough alone. You came in here like **a herd of elephants**."?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not in your scenario, but a *group of people who don't mind their own business* could be called **rubberneckers**:

> a person who turns their head to stare at something in a foolish manner, esp. while driving a car.

<sup>[*NOAD*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/rubberneck?q=rubbernecker#rubberneck__11)</sup>