# what is the person who is always nosing in people's business?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

what is a person called who is always nosing on other people's business - like having a neighbor always outside on the balcony or window to check the neighborhood out.

Comment: related: [What is a good word(s) for someone who excessively asks for information that they have no business knowing?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/276549/what-is-a-good-words-for-someone-who-excessively-asks-for-information-that-the/276555#276555) and [What would you call a group of people who don't mind their own business?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103081/what-would-you-call-a-group-of-people-who-dont-mind-their-own-business)
]

Comment: This question has been asked time and time again. Look up the word [nosy in a thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/nosy) and you have a feast of words to choose from. Why this question has earned 2 upvotes (so far) is beyond my comprehension.

Answer (score 2):

***[Busybody](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/busybody)***  is a term you can use:

> - a person who is too interested in the private lives of other people

(M-W)

- [Are You Like My Busybody Neighbor?](http://www.peoplefirstps.com/are-you-like-my-busybody-neighbor/)

also:
***[Nosy Parker](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/nosy-parker)*** 
(n, Informal):

> - a persistently nosy, prying person.

(Dictionary.com)